# In Need of Help Troubleshooting Issues with Repeated Questions on the Child Form Not Showing Up in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I created a child survey form under a new case list (Image 1). I made it such that the Household Form would create an child case if the answer to the survey question, "Are there any children under 60 months of age who live in this household" is "Yes". I also save the variable capturing the number of children who are under 60 months as a case property under the child case (Image 2).

However, even if a household notes that they have children under 60 months old, the repeating questions that I put on the child form (or any of the questions for that matter; see Image 3), do not appear when I am testing the app? Is there any reason why?

See the images below for reference:

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

Image 3:
[image: Image 3]

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated! Thanks!